# How Can I Update WHMCS Domain Pricing For 1st - 10th year (with all years in between) from a .csv please

Tags: domains, whmcs, csv

I am starting out and on an extremely low budget, nor am I a coder.

WHMCS is missing some key functionality including any documentation with creating a .csv to upload prices. I need to update my prices extremely regularly in order to take into account foreign exchange rates so I don't end up losing money.

They also don't make the CSS particularly friendly on the bulk pricing updater that exists - this will not allow you to take into account first year price manually added and multiply from there for the other years even though the tick box is there.

The easiest way would be to use libreoffice calc for my formulas and then run an update from there but there is absolutely nothing on Google other than a ton of requests to WHCMS over the last decade for the functionality.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are "starting out and on an extremely low budget" WHMCS is the wrong choice.  They have recently increased their prices significantly to the point where I regard it as "gouging".  My annual cost rose by over 300% and others suffered more.

You are absolutely correct that "WHMCS is missing some key functionality".  There is a function to import prices but it only works for some registries.

**To answer your question** about updating domain pricing for multiple years without coding, you have to do it manually, domain by domain, and that is tedious beyond belief.

If you are interested in getting the domains list in alphabetical order, a task they make effectively impossible, have a look at a blog post where I explained how to do it [here](https://blog.123host.net.au/reorder-domains-in-whmcs/).  You could also have a look at other posts in the WHMCS category where I have shared some fixes for missing functionality.